# Set of subgradients at the intersection of k hyperplanes

Tags: polytopes, convex-geometry, subgradient

How to find the set of subgradients at the $(n-k)$-dimensional "edge" created by the intersection of $k$ hyperplanes $(k \lt n)$, say:

$a_{11}x_1+...+a_{1n}x_n=b_1,\\
a_{21}x_1+...+a_{2n}x_n=b_2,\\...\\
a_{k1}x_1+...+a_{kn}x_n=b_k;\\ 
a_{ij} \in \Bbb R$

For two hyperplanes (take the first and second hyperplanes above, e.g.) I think it's everything in between the subgradients of the two hyperplanes, i.e. the set

$S=[a_{11},a_{21}] \times [a_{12},a_{22}] \times...\times[a_{1n},a_{2n}]$

(Assuming $a_{1j} \leq a_{2j} \forall j=1(1)n$)

Is that correct. 
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I think the set is the set of all possible convex combinations of the subgradients of the intersecting hyperplanes. Is that correct?

Comment: The more hyperplanes you add (to the intersection) the more dimensions you take out and hence the bigger the set of subgradients becomes. Am I right?